# How can I get partial data from a full outer join between a view and a function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm doing a full outer join on a view and a function:

```
SELECT vw.*,fnc.*
FROM MyView AS vw 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
dbo.MyFunction() AS fnc 
ON vw.Name=fnc.Name
WHERE vw.Name='THING'
```

For some values of 'THING', I get all the fields returned from the view and function; however, if the function wouldn't normally return a value for 'THING' (ie. `"SELECT * FROM dbo.MyFunction() WHERE Name='THING'` returns NULL), I don't get anything back. Is there a way to still return the values from the view (which always exist), even if no values are returned from the function?

Comment: If there is a row in `MyView` that has `'THING'`, then your query should return that row, regardless of matches in `fnc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, your query should do what you want.  It would be more clearly written as:

```
SELECT vw.*, fnc.*
FROM MyView vw LEFT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.MyFunction() fnc 
     ON vw.Name = fnc.Name 
WHERE vw.Name = 'THING';
```

This emphasizes that you want the rows in the view with `'THING'`.

I suspect you may have misstated the problem.  If you want all `'THINGS'` from either the view or the function, then perhaps:

```
SELECT vw.*, fnc.*
FROM MyView vw FULL OUTER JOIN
     dbo.MyFunction() fnc 
     ON vw.Name = fnc.Name
WHERE vw.Name = 'THING' OR fnc.Name = 'THING'
```

is what you are really looking for.

Comment: I see what the problem was, it was a mistake on my part. I actually had `...WHERE fnc.Name = 'THING'` in my actual code; which was causing nothing to be returned since the function wasn't returning that data.

Comment: Yes. `vw.Name = 'THING'` will exclude `vw.Name IS NULL`. So this is not actually the answer.....